# How can we get the location in android without turning on GPS

Tags: android, android-location

How can we retrieve the location in android with out turning on GPS. I was able to get the location using the GPS,NETWORK Providers. When the GPS was disabled not able to get the coordinates. Could anyone help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: @JigneshJain i have been trying from yerterday i was not able to get the location when the gps was off

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through this tutorial.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Here is the sample code you can use to retrieve location from default location provider.

```
public class ShowLocation extends Activity implements LocationListener {
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  private String provider;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
      System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
      onLocationChanged(location);
    }
  }

  /* Request updates at startup */
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
  }

  /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
    double lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());
  }

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Add the following permissions to your application in your AndroidManifest.xml file

- INTERNET
- ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
- ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

I hope this helps.

Comment: It was showing diabled GPS Toast message i would like to know the location when gps was disabled

Comment: @Teja change the second parameter to "true".Check my edited answer: provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true); this will return only provider that is enabled.

Comment: Still it requires Gps to be Enabled

Comment: if your gps is disabled and network is enabled then it will take network provider as location provider. Its working at my side. Please try the exact code above.

Comment: I turned on my wifi and disabled my gps it is anot working if i turn on gps it is working fine

Comment: @Teja as per i know its network provider(sim network) or gps which provides location ...Wifi will only provide accuracy.

Comment: but when my gps was off i was not able to retrive the location

Comment: It requires Location must be enabled for the network location to be working else it still useless!

Answer (score 0):

Getting Location using network providers:

```
boolean network_enabled = isNetworkAvailable();
Location location = null;
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

if(network_enabled)
location = SLOC_locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

The isNetworkAvailabel() function:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) SLOC_context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();

}
```